# How does UserService class work?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, gae-userservice

I am trying to implement a login system using the Android Studio LoginActivity template. On AppEngine, I try the two lines:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
```

but the user is always null. 
How is it supposed to function and be implemented? 
I mean, does UserService class only work when integrating the Login with Google Accounts?

If yes, what is the best and smartest way for me to implement a customized login system?

Comment: what do u mean by customized?

Comment: I mean not using the Google Accounts API

Comment: if i understand it correct u need to have a server setup for account verification. and use some web services to call them from the android site.

Comment: UserService is not for that. Will only work when loading a webpage from a browser, not as an ajax call to appengine. The appengine docs explain how to implement such user validations with userService including a custom one not depending on google accounts

Comment: Could you provide a link or an example? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, UserService class only work when integrating the Login with Google Accounts (Gmail or Apps), and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/#Java_User_authentication_in_Java) is how you can handle that.

About the customized login system, there isn't a correct answer, you need to implement a system of API (login, register, reset password, ...) based on your needs. Surely you need a datastore entity which preserves the account information and the password for the login process.